# Why does the engine evaluate black's position as better here?

Tags: engines, analysis, endgame

I recently played a game as white, that ended in a draw. I thought I had a big advantage at some point, but when analyzing it, the engine says that black was actually in favor ~ -1.1.

I was a central pawn up, pieces fairly active, and I couldn't figure out why the computer liked black's position more. Can someone please help me here?

```
[Title "White to move"]
[fen "2rq1k2/5bp1/2Q2p1p/p7/P2P1P2/6P1/5K1P/B3R3 w - - 0 1"]
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Did you look at the engine's top line? That is often a good way to understand the crux of a position,to play through the engine line.
But anyway,to answer your question,in the given position, first from a general sense, black's king is actually quite safe and here is a good rule of thumb, I do not remember the text from which I got this but it is a good rule to know,
"In Opposite colored bishops middlegames, one side is often functionally up a piece owing to attacks on the opposing color complex"
In this case, black has light squared weaknesses which are excellently covered by the f7 bishop and which renders your b2 bishop useless, for now, plus that bishop is hemmed in by your d4 pawn which is isolated and weak, while you have huge light squared weaknesses along h1-a8 and black's LSB can for eg occupy D5 which blockades your pawn and controls the diagonal. Also noteworthy is that if an opposite color bishop endgame is reached, a bishop on d5 cuts off the black king beautifully from the game!
(the d5 advance is stopped by blacks queen and bishop)
these are the general or strategic components of the position, the engine would be much better at the concrete possibilities of the position.